# PhantomJS; If I set a variable inside page.evaluate(), how can I access the value of that variable outside of page.evaluate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs

Using PhantomJS consider the following code snippet:

```
var reloadAfterLogin = false;
function(user, pass, debug){ // step 3 submit Login
   page.evaluate(function(user, pass, debug){
     if($("form").attr("action").indexOf("login.do") > 0){
       reloadAfterLogin = true;
       $('form').submit();
     }
   }, user, pass, debug);
 },
```

As I understand it, this is more than just a scope issue. The code executing inside of page.evaluate() is a complete separate instance of JavaScript. I have to admit I'm still having a hard time wrapping my head around how PhantomJS works but I need access to the reloadAfterLogin variable outside of page.evaluate(). How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `return` from the [`evaluate`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html) callbacks. I guess you want

```
function(user, pass, debug){ // step 3 submit Login
  reloadAfterLogin = page.evaluate(function(user, pass, debug){
    if($("form").attr("action").indexOf("login.do") > 0){
      $('form').submit();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }, user, pass, debug);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot return from evaluate callbacks as described by Bergi for whatever reason, you can use a hacky workaround by misusing [onConsoleMessage](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html):

Send your data as JSON from within webpage.evaluate() like so:

```
console.log('{"foo": "bar"}');
```

You can then extract this data to the global space (outside webpage.evaluate()):

```
webpage.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
  var obj = JSON.parse(msg);
  // Do whatever you like with obj...
};
```

Comment: Interesting! I like it.